# Reading CSV creates too many rows/columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am working with dataframes in the pandas library. I have a table of data in Excel that I save as a CSV then I call

`df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")`

I expect the frame to look something like

```
   Item1  Item2  Item3
0  12.00      3      2
1   4.00      8      4
2   3.14      2      8
```

But instead I get

```
   Item1  Item2  Item3 Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4
0  12.00      3      2        NaN        NaN
1   4.00      8      4        NaN        NaN
2   3.14      2      8        NaN        NaN
```

Or sometimes extra rows with all `NaN` values. It appears that `pandas` is not aware of the real size of the CSV. The data in Excel is organized perfectly fine, the data values are all nonempty and are entirely in a rectangle. How do I fix this? Is there an edit I can make to the CSV that will specify the its correct size?

As requested here is a snippet of the data. It goes down to about 2500 rows, and there are no more values to the right.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a short sample of the actual data file?

Comment: @Simon It's up now!

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the actual csv raw text as viewed in an editor like notepad, not the table view in Excel? I don't think there is anything going on with pandas here, I would be has something to do with your data set.

Comment: A common problem with csv parsing is the delimiter, make sure that you your data columns do not contain your delimiter. It does not seem like this is the case for you. The only think i can think of is your row endline character might not be matching your machine's expected endline/newline character

Comment: 95% sure the csv is dirty

Comment: Okay, I just opened it in a text file, I can see the problem very well now. There's tons of commas at the end of rows and a couple rows of nothing but commas. Anyone know why this happened when the data in Excel is clean (or at least appears to be so), and I saved as a CSV from Excel?

Comment: Excel essentially just does what pandas is doing when parsing the file. The difference is pandas will represent missing values as nan, but excel will just display it as blank. So there are probably a bunch of junk cells/columns in the excel file, you just cant see them

Comment: Make sure you delete the rows/columns in excel and not just blank out the data.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a cell that is not empty (for example a space ) in the original Excel file. If you are getting 2 unnamed columns in pandas, try to delete 2 columns of the original Excel file.

Another way would be to keep all columns that are not `unnamed`. You could do this with:

```
real_cols = [x for x in df.columns if not x.startswith("Unnamed: ")]
df = df[real_cols]
```

And then you can save the csv.